# PyGTK Treeview automatic filters on each column

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I have created a TreeView with several columns and the corresponding ListStore that holds the data.

What I would like to do now is to automatically create a dropdown under each column that will hold the distinct values of that column and perform filtering. So basically I want to create an excel like auto filter functionality.

Can this be achieved via the TreeView control? Are there any other controls out in the wild that can provide something like that?

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with TreeView/TreeStore in Python but I haven't tried exactly what you are looking for.  There's some promising stuff in the C docs, though:

- [`gtk_tree_view_column_set_widget`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTreeViewColumn.html#gtk-tree-view-column-set-widget) to put your menu button in the column header
- [`gtk_tree_view_column_set_clickable`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTreeViewColumn.html#gtk-tree-view-column-set-clickable) to make it clickable

So it looks to me like you take your `Gtk.TreeViewColumn` object, call `col.set_widget(my_menu_widget)` on it, possibly call `col.set_clickable(True)`, and Bob's yer uncle.